# text и textvariable для одного виджета одновременно

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, виджет

Мне нужно чтобы на этом `Label` отображался постоянно определенный текст, а в конце его было число, которое менялось бы. Я не знаю как это сделать.

Единственное что приходит в голову это `IntVar`, но если я укажу в опциях виджета опцию `text` и одновременно опцию `textvariable`, то отображаться на этом виджете будет только последняя. Надо что-то вроде такого, или вообще другое решение

```
number = IntVar()
number.set(1)
Label(root, text="Number =  ", textvariable=number)
```

Потом командой менять эту переменную

```
def change():
    number.set(number.get + 1)
```

Команда вызывается кнопкой

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FIX_PART = "Number = "
var_part = "1"
str_num = StringVar()
str_num.set(FIX_PART + var_part)
Label(root, textvariable=str_num)

def change():
    old_val = str_num.get()
    var_part = old_val[len(FIX_PART):]
    num = int(var_part)
    vart_part = str(num + 1)
    str_num.set(FIX_PART + var_part)
```